# Regular Expression in R - Spaces before and after the text

Tags: r, regex

I have a stats file that has lines that are like this:
"system.l2.compressor.compression_size::1 0 # Number of blocks that compressed to fit in 1 bits"

0 is the value that I care about in this case. The spaces between the actual statistic and whatever is before and after it are not the same each time.

My code is something like that to try and get the stats.

```
if (grepl("system.l2.compressor.compression_size::1", line))
    {
      matches <- regmatches(line, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]", line))
      compression_size_1 = as.numeric(unlist(matches))[1]
    }
```

The reason I have this regular expression

```
[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]
```

is because in other cases the statistic is a decimal number. I don't anticipate in the cases that are like the example I posted for the numbers to be decimals, but it would be nice to have a "fail safe" regex that can capture even such a case.

In this case I get "2." "1" "0" "1" as answers. How can I restrict it so that I can get only the true stat as the answer?

I tried using something like this

```
"[:space:][[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]][:space:]"
```

or other variations, but either I get back NA, or the same numbers but with spaces surrounding them.

Comment: Your data is structured as "[first block] [statistic] [second block]. You have digits in the first block that are throwing you off. Try something like "::[[:digit:]] +([[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*) +". You'll see I used parens () to capture the statistic. Could you try that and clarify your post with more sample data?

Comment: What this gives me back is "::1 0 ". (I've deleted the extra spaces). The rest of the lines that I'm interested in will be the same. 
i.e., "system.l2.compressor.compression_size::256 58740 # Number of blocks that compressed to fit in 256 bits"
or "system.l2.compressor.encoding::Base8_1 58731 # Number of data entries that match encoding Base8_1"

For example in the last one I get back  "2."    "8"     "1"     "58731" "8"     "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple base R possibilities depending on how your data is set up. In the future, it is helpful to provide a reproducible example. Definitely provide one if these don't work. If the pattern works, it will probably be faster to adapt it to a `stringr` or `stringi` function. Good luck!!

```
# The digits after the space after the anything not a space following "::"
gsub(".*::\\S+\\s+(\\d+).*", "\\1", strings)
[1] "58740" "58731" "70576"

# Getting the digit(s) following a space and preceding a space and pound sign
gsub(".*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+#.*", "\\1", strings)
[1] "58740" "58731" "70576"

# Combining the two (this is the most restrictive)
gsub(".*::\\S+\\s+(\\d+)\\s+#.*", "\\1", strings)
[1] "58740" "58731" "70576"

# Extracting the first digits surounded by spaces (least restrictive)
gsub(".*?\\s+(\\d+)\\s+.*", "\\1", strings)
[1] "58740" "58731" "70576"

# Or, using stringr for the last pattern:
as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(strings, "\\s+\\d+\\s+"))
[1] 58740 58731 70576
```

EDIT: Explanation for the second one:

```
gsub(".*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+#.*", "\\1", strings)
```

- `.*` - `.`=any character except \n; `*`=any number of times
- `\\s+` - `\\s` =whitespace; `+`=at least one instance (of the whitespace)
- `(\\d+)` - `()`=capture group, you can reference it later by the number of occurrences (i.e., the `”\\1”` returns the first instance of this pattern); `\\d`=digit; `+`=at least one instance (of a digit)
- `\\s+#` - `\\s` =whitespace; `+`=at least one instance (of the whitespace); `#` a literal pound sign
- `.*` - `.`=any character except \n; `*`=any number of times

**Data**:

```
strings <- c("system.l2.compressor.compression_size::256 58740 # Number of blocks that compressed to fit in 256 bits",
             "system.l2.compressor.encoding::Base*.8_1 58731 # Number of data entries that match encoding Base8_1",
             "system.l2.overall_hits::.cpu.data 70576 # number of overall hits")
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried your first code and it worked fine for all the occasions when there were numbers before and after the actual statistics. But if there is not number after them, then the entire line is given back as the match.
For example in this case: "system.l2.overall_hits::.cpu.data               70576                       # number of overall hits", I get the entire line as a match and an NA for the actual value. Could you also mind explaining how your code works?

Comment: Hey @vic, you can swap out the `\\w` for `[A-z0-9_.]` to manually specify the "allowed" characters following the `::`. I can definitely explain the regex later tonight or tomorrow morning when I am back at my computer.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I used the 2nd option. Could you mind explaining that one?

Comment: Hey @vic, just updated it. Hope it helps! This [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) usually helps me, and I know some people love the [regex101 website](https://regex101.com). Let me know if anything is still unclear (as I only explained the pattern).