# Regular expression in R - Text between strings, Digit between strings and digit and text after strings

Tags: r, regex

I have several question about regular expressions in R, which are related to [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384597/regular-expression-in-r-spaces-before-and-after-the-text) my previous posts in stack overflow but is a bit more expansive.

I have lines in a text file that represent stats. I load these files in R and want to get the values of some of these statistics.

First case, statistics of this type:

```
system.cpu.dcache.overall_accesses::.cpu.data     42519477                       # number of overall (read+write) accesses
system.l2.overall_accesses::.cpu.data         1335898                       # number of overall (read+write) accesses
system.l3.overall_accesses::.cpu.data         1331502                       # number of overall (read+write) accesses
```

In this case, I want to catch the cache level as string (which is between "system." and ."overall_accesses") and the value as integer that is between the whitespaces.

cache_level = "cpu.dcache" or "l2" or "l3"
value = "42519477" etc.

Second case:

```
system.l3.compressor.compression_size::256 58740 # Number of blocks that compressed to fit in 256 bits"
system.l3.compressor.compression_size::256 65742 # Number of blocks that compressed to fit in 512 bits"
```

In this case, I want to catch the cache level as string, the value as integer, as well as the compression size (i.e. 256 or 512). The compression size is always gonna be a number.

compression_size = "256" or "512"

Third case:

```
system.l2.compressor.encoding::Base4_1 87521 # Number of data entries that match encoding Base4_1
system.l2.compressor.encoding::Base8_1 58731 # Number of data entries that match encoding Base8_1
system.l2.compressor.encoding::Uncompressed 24125 # Number of data entries that match encoding Uncompressed
```

This case is similar to the second one, in that I want to get the same things, but the encoding is a string.

compression_encoding = "Base4_1" or "Base8_1" or "Uncompressed"

For getting the lines I have in mind something like this:

```
For first: if (grepl("system.+\\.*.overall_accesses::.cpu.data", line))
For second: if (grepl("system.\\.*.compressor.compression_size::\\d+", line))
For third: if (grepl("system.\\.*.compressor.encoding::\\.*", line))
```

I'm not sure whether these will work though. Then I need to get the different data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mostly figured things out. Not in the most elegant way though, which was what I was hoping for in an answer here.

For the first case:

```
if (grepl("system.+\\.*.overall_accesses::.cpu.data", line)) {
  stat_line <- regmatches(line, gregexpr("system..*.overall_accesses::.cpu.data", line))
  cache_name <- gsub('system.\\s*|\\s*.overall.*$', '', stat_line)
  if (cache_name == "cpu.dcache") cache_name <- "dcache"
  stat <- "overall_accesses_data"
  value <- gsub(".*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+#.*", "\\1", line)
}
```

For the second case:

```
if (grepl("system.+\\.*.compressor.compression_size::\\d+", line)) {
  stat_line <- regmatches(line, gregexpr("system.+\\.*.compressor.compression_size::\\d+", line))
  cache_name <- gsub('system.\\s*|\\s*.compressor.*$', '', stat_line)
  stat <- paste("compression_size", gsub('.*::\\s*|\\s*', '', stat_line), sep="_")
  value <- gsub(".*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+#.*", "\\1", line)
}
```

For the third case:

```
if (grepl("system.l\\d.compressor.encoding::", line)) {
  stat_line <- regmatches(line, gregexpr("system.l\\d.compressor.encoding::.*\\s+", line))
  cache_name <- gsub('system.\\s*|\\s*.compressor.*$', '', stat_line)
  cache_level[length(cache_level)+1] <- cache_name
  stat[length(stat)+1] <- paste("encoding", gsub('.*encoding::(\\w+)\\s+.*', '\\1', stat_line), sep="_")
  value[length(value)+1] <- gsub(".*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+#.*", "\\1", line)
}
```

And in order to make the answers more generic as per the title:

Grabbing text between strings: (case of cache name)

```
gsub('system.\\s*|\\s*.overall.*$', '', stat_line)
```

Grabbing digits between strings: (case of stat values)

```
gsub(".*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+#.*", "\\1", line)
```

Grabbing digits after strings: (case of compression size)

```
gsub('.*::\\s*|\\s*', '', stat_line)
```

Grabbing text or a mixture of text and digits after strings: (case of encoding)

```
gsub('.*encoding::(\\w+)\\s+.*', '\\1', stat_line)
```

Thanks to prosoitos for helping with the last case.

Answer (score 3):

I developped *unglue* to solve a similar use case, see:

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)
x <- c(
"system.cpu.dcache.overall_accesses::.cpu.data     42519477",
"system.l2.overall_accesses::.cpu.data         1335898     ",
"system.l3.overall_accesses::.cpu.data         1331502     ",
"system.l3.compressor.compression_size::256 58740",
"system.l3.compressor.compression_size::256 65742",
"system.l2.compressor.encoding::Base4_1 87521",
"system.l2.compressor.encoding::Base8_1 58731",
"system.l2.compressor.encoding::Uncompressed 24125")

patterns <- c(
  "system.{cache_level}.overall_accesses{=[^0-9]*}{value=\\d+}{=.*?}",
  "system.{cache_level}.compressor.compression_size::{compression_size} {value=\\d+}{=.*?}",
  "system.{cache_level}.compressor.encoding::{encoding} {value=\\d+}{=.*?}")

unglue_data(x, patterns)
#>   cache_level    value compression_size     encoding
#> 1  cpu.dcache 42519477             <NA>         <NA>
#> 2          l2  1335898             <NA>         <NA>
#> 3          l3  1331502             <NA>         <NA>
#> 4          l3    58740              256         <NA>
#> 5          l3    65742              256         <NA>
#> 6          l2    87521             <NA>      Base4_1
#> 7          l2    58731             <NA>      Base8_1
#> 8          l2    24125             <NA> Uncompressed
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

- patterns are tried one by one, the first that matches is used
- when a `{subpattern}` doesn't contain `=` it matches anything (equivalent to `.*?`)
- when it starts with `=` without a left hand side, the value matched by the subpattern is not extracted

Read more about it there: https://github.com/moodymudskipper/unglue

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in which form you want your output, but here is a suggestion using `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)

text <- readLines("/path/to/your/file")

cache_level <-
  text %>%
  str_subset("^system\\..*\\.overall_accesses") %>% 
  str_replace_all("^system\\.(.*)\\.overall_accesses.*", "\\1")

value <- text %>%
  str_subset("^system\\.(.*)\\.overall_accesses") %>% 
  str_replace_all(".*\\s+(\\d+)\\s+.*", "\\1") %>%
  as.numeric()

compression_size <- text %>%
  str_subset(".*compression_size.*") %>% 
  str_replace_all(".*compression_size::(\\d+)\\s+.*", "\\1") %>%
  as.numeric()

compression_encoding <-
  text %>%
  str_subset(".*encoding.*") %>% 
  str_replace_all(".*encoding::(\\w+)\\s+.*", "\\1")
```

Output:

```
> cache_level
[1] "cpu.dcache" "l2"         "l3"        
> value
[1] 42519477  1335898  1331502
> compression_size
[1] 256 256
> compression_encoding
[1] "Base4_1"      "Base8_1"      "Uncompressed"
```